# Show full conversation in search folders?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, search

I want to create search folders that search for emails that have a category assigned, for example.  And for every email that has that category found, I want to show the whole conversation in the search folder's view.  Basically, I want to be able to search for something within a conversation instead of within an email.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if I have a set of emails that outlook considers a "conversation", it usually starts with an email from or to me, then me and various other people reply back and forth.  If I assign a category to one of those emails, I would like the search folder to show that whole conversation.  If I search on that category, it filters out the rest of the emails in that conversation.  I don't think I can do this in Outlook without 3rd party software, but maybe I can and haven't figured it out.  I'll have to look into Xobni and Lookeen.

Comment: This is available, at least for newer versions of Outlook, as detailed in this other thread: https://superuser.com/a/1009647/23996

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, although there doesn't seem to be a way to do this in 2007, 2010 does seem to support this, and it doesn't have to be a search folder.  Conversation Settings includes a "Show Messages from other folders" option that is wonderful.

Comment: `Show as Conversations` is not an option in `Search Folders` unfortunately.

Comment: It is there for me, in Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 3):

Well as you already noticed, there are search tools available which can help you with your problem, I also prefer lookeen, which is very good in displaying conversations and of course you don't need to create Search Folders, which by the way is a waste of time, when you have a good search tool.

Comment: I want search folders, or some other flavor of saved search criteria, because repeatedly re-entering the same search criteria everyday is a waste of time for me when with a search folder all I have to do is click on it.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) for this purpose.

Comment: Xobni looks like a nice tool, and it does seem to be able to search for conversation the way I want to.  But Xobni does not seem to be able to filter on categories and some other things too, which I would need.  And Xobni does not seem to have any thing similar to search folders, which is a big convenience for me.  In the end, it isn't solving my problem.  Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on *Search Folders* and select *New Search Folder...*. 
In the *New Search Folder* window scroll down to select *Categorized mail* then click the *Choose* button to select the category you want to search (or multiple categories).

Then all you have to do is to customize current view in the new created search folder - right click on the header and select "Conversation" (or go to View | Current View | Conversation)

Let us know if this is what you needed.

Comment: The problem with this is I want the whole conversation to show up, even if only 1 email matched the search criteria.